# How Does Neelix Know About the War?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, space

In SE4 EP4, Nemesis, Janeway asks Neelix what he knows about the war on the planet Chakotay is marooned on. Neelix knows about it.

However, in Season 3, Neelix is forced to go to lengths to get a map because he doesn’t know what is beyond the Nekrit Expanse, as he hadn’t gone beyond it. Now they have been thrown beyond Borg space thanks to Kes.

So HOW can Neelix possibly know ANYTHING about this planet? He can’t have talked to the ambassador because Tuvok was the one who had communicated to him.

Comment: I believe it is the Nekrit Expanse, not Necrotic

Comment: Maybe he'd heard of the place but doesn't know its exact location. I know that there was a war at Thermopylae but I'd be hard-pressed to find it on a map of Greece.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Neelix was still the ship's ambassador, and his duties in that regard would require him to be in contact with local authorities. During such conversations he would be trying to find out anything that would help Janeway, such as local hazards or areas to avoid. A planet at war would certain fall into that category.

The fact that he hadn't already briefed Janeway on it would be a good followup question. But maybe the planned course through the sector wasn't in that direction and he felt it wasn't worth including in his updates.

Comment: Tuvok knowing about the planet and how to contact them I think lends credence to this. Even if Neelix didn't inform Janeway about the planet, Tuvok would still have wanted to know about any potential threats to the ship regardless.